# How do you force Outlook 2007 to re-index it's seach on Windows XP SP 3?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, outlook, outlook-2007, indexing

So I have a Windows XP SP 3 machine which is running Outlook 2007. When I search in Outlook for an email that exists using a basic keyword, like say "MySQL", I get no results. However, Outlook gives me the following message:

> Search results may be incomplete
>   because items are still being indexed.
>   Click here for more details.

When I click, I get the following:

> Outlook is currently indexing your
>   items. 
> Search results may be
>   incomplete because items are still
>   being indexed. 
> 8783 items remaining in
>   "Mailbox - USER" 
> 8812 items remaining
>   across all open mailboxes.

The thing is, these are the numbers it has been reporting for several days, and Outlook is open for 8 hours a day. It does not seem like the index is working. As best I can tell, the index seemed to stop about 3 weeks ago.

How can I force Outlook 2007 to re-index everything and start working properly again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an article for that :)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA102378321033.aspx

Comment: The above link is dead. This could be pertinent in its place https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Reset-indexing-by-rebuilding-your-Instant-Search-catalog-213a2728-0ef4-427a-9bb2-aed329a59b17 which also links to [Instant Search is not finding items](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Instant-Search-is-not-finding-items-1eb50282-0fa3-4a04-8db4-ee1c14fa97ab?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA)

Comment: this is why link only answers are VERY bad, please include the pertinent content from the links

Answer (score 0):

#### For Windows

- In Microsoft Windows click the **Start** button, and then click **Control Panel**
- Do one of the following:

  - **Windows Vista** Click **System Maintenance** and then click **Indexing Options**

> *in classic view, double-click **Indexing Options***

- **Microsoft Windows XP** Under **See Also**, click **Other Control Panel Options** and then click **Indexing Options**

> *in classic view, double-click **Indexing Options***

- **Windows 7**  click **Category** under **View By**, change the view to either **Small Icons** or **Large Icons** and click **Indexing Options**
- Click **Advanced**
- Click **Rebuild**